# Python file imports using a string

Tags: python

I am trying to import a function from another python file in a different directory but only have the function name in string form. I have tried using import lib as follows:

```
sys.path.insert(1, file_path) # Works fine
import file # Works fine
run_function = importlib.import_module("file.function"+str(loop)) # Error occurs here
```

But when I try this I get the error message: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file.function1'; 'file' is not a package`

I have also tried doing:

```
from file import *
eval("function{loop}()")
```

But with this method I recieve the error message: `SyntaxError: import * only allowed at module level`

I am not sure exactly how to fix the issue or whether there would be a better way of doing this. I am open to suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: You did `import file`, so your code knows the name of the module, correct?

Comment: yes, it knows the name of the module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't import functions. You have successfully imported the module, which includes the function, so all you have to do is get it

```
sys.path.insert(1, file_path) # Works fine
import file # Works fine
result = getattr(file, "function1")(loop)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import anywhere in the file (obviously importing within a function would limit the module scope to the function itself).

```
def func(x):
    for i in range(x):
        eval(f"from lib import function{i}")

    # All functions available in this scope
```

For extra safety, I recommend this be put into a try/catch.